# What package or commands are needed to format section titles(subtitles) to the left of text blocks?

Tags: header-footer

[image]

I am new to LaTeX and have searched around for templates and examples, but have not found much. I looked at `fancyheaders` package but was unable to ascertain whether the setup was possible in a simple and straightforward manner. I searched left side headers, and headers overtop margins and google images produced very few to no results for this style.

Comment: These are called *sections* - check package `titlesec`.  Anyway, mi suggestion would be to look at comprehensive packages to style books, like `memoir` or `scrbook`. BTW, welcome!

Comment: Text in margins can be placed with `\reversemarginpar` and `\marginpar`. See for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256267/section-titles-in-margin-notes) to place section as margin notes. But I would first look for  alternatives styles, like  [hitec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99707/11604), even if you want a wide margin to take notes or so, since the margin is never a good place for  headers with more than one or two words.

Comment: If you are new to LaTeX, I suggest you not to learn LaTeX but rather learn OpTeX.  You'll see that customization of the layout of the pages there is very easy, and everything else is much easier, elegant and understandable too.  http://petr.olsak.net/optex/

Answer (score 1):

`titlesec` allows you to redefine the section commands. You can use `\titleformat` with the option `leftmargin`, to move the heading in the, well, left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{2.5cm}{*2.5}{0.5cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}[leftmargin]{\normalfont}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{2.5cm}{*2.5}{0.5cm}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]